# Number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts with each part at most $1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am trying to figure out a formula for the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts with each part at most $1$.

I know that the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. I think that I can obtain the formula by taking

$\text{(# of $k$-compositions of $n$)}-\text{(# of $k$-compositions of $n$, each part $\geq$ $2$)}$

However, I keep getting a negative number because I keep getting that the number of $k$-compositions of $n$ with each part $\geq$ $2$ is $\binom{n+2k-1}{k-1}$. Some help, please?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The complement of all parts at most $1$ is at least one part of at least $2$, not all parts of at least $2$.  You need $n\ 1$'s and $k-n\ 0$'s, so are choosing the location of the $1$'s in the list. You can do that in $k\choose n$ ways.

Comment: What if $k<n$? That would give me zero...

Comment: That is correct. If you require all parts to be $0$ or $1$ you must have at least as many parts as you want the sum to be.

Comment: @FelipeSegundo Do you think zero is the wrong answer in case $k\lt n$?

Comment: I think $0$ is correct if $k \lt n$ Try $k=2, n=3$.  How can you compose $3$ out of $2$ parts, each at most $1$?

Comment: Ahhh Okay, I see what you are saying. When $k<n$ it is not possible to have compositions with all parts at most $1$.